# Unable to check object from Hazelcast queue

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have created a queue. I put some object here. My intention is to check each object prior to insert in order to avoid duplicate entry adding to the queue. so I am using contains() method. but for same entry , it returns false value. I override method equals and hashCode also. please help.

Comment: how did you override them

Comment: yes, overridden those methods. still no go.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast checks equals based on binary content and doesn't make use of your equals/hash. In some cases this can cause problems, e.g. if you use a hashmap in your structure and you serialize it. The same objects can result in different byte-content. To deal with this issue you might consider using one of the custom Serialization API's of Hazelcast like DataSerializable and don't use java serializable.

Another problem is that your approach is inherently race:

```
if(!queue.contains(item)){
    queue.put(item)
}
```

The contains and put are not atomic, so it could be that 2 threads at the same time call the contains for the same item and both decide that the item is not on the queue and both add it.

Perhaps the queue is not your friend in this case, the IMap is a lot more flexible. In your case you don't care about the values, so you can do something like this:

```
 map.put(item,item)
```

Or use a nonsense value if your item is very big.